# Faces notifications not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am having a strange issue with the Faces messages.

Sometimes, the `<p:growl>, <p:messages>` display correctly the notification after executing some method. But there are specific JSF pages where no notification is shown.

For example:

```
public String create() {
    try {
        getFacade().create(current);
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("NotaCreated"));
        return prepareCreate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        return null;
    }
}
```

The method is called in

```
<h:commandLink action="#{notaController.create}" value="#{bundle.CreateNotaSaveLink}"/>
```

And it does not show the notification. But for other entities as well as for other operations the messages are displayed correctly. This happens also in other functions, where I need feedback and it is not shown as expected.

I've been searching around and read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408130/jsf-commandbutton-works-on-second-click) and tried some of the suggested solutions, including setting the `ajax=false` attribute in commandButtons and commandLinks or using the scripts posted, but none of that worked for me, so I ask this question hoping that someone can help me.

Do I have to configure something to make it work correctly? I need this to get fixed by tomorrow and I don't know what else to do.

Update:

These are the JsfUtil methods:

```
public static void addSuccessMessage(String msg) {
    FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, msg, msg);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("successInfo", facesMsg);
}
public static void addErrorMessage(Exception ex, String defaultMsg) {
    String msg = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
    if (msg != null && msg.length() > 0) {
        addErrorMessage(msg);
    } else {
        addErrorMessage(defaultMsg);
    }
}
```

This is the Create.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.CreateNotaTitle}"></h:outputText>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
            <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateNotaLabel_fecha}" for="fecha" />
                <p:calendar value="#{notaController.selected.fecha}" id="fecha"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateNotaLabel_observaciones}" for="observaciones" />
                <p:inputTextarea rows="4" cols="30" id="observaciones" value="#{notaController.selected.observaciones}" title="#{bundle.CreateNotaTitle_observaciones}" />
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateNotaLabel_tipoNota}" for="tipoNota" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoNota" value="#{notaController.selected.tipoNota}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateNotaRequiredMessage_tipoNota}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="---"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="debito" itemLabel="Débito"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="credito" itemLabel="Crédito"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateNotaLabel_monto}" for="monto" />
                <p:inputText id="monto" value="#{notaController.selected.monto}" title="#{bundle.CreateNotaTitle_monto}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateNotaRequiredMessage_monto}"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateNotaLabel_factura}" for="factura" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="factura" converter="#{facturaController.convertidor}" value="#{notaController.selected.factura}" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateNotaRequiredMessage_factura}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="---"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{facturaController.facturas}" var="factura" itemValue="#{factura}" itemLabel="#{factura.idFactura}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

            </h:panelGrid>
            <br />
            <h:commandLink action="#{notaController.create}" value="#{bundle.CreateNotaSaveLink}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{cargaController.crearCargaDefault(sesionMB.usuario)}"
                                             target="#{notaController.selected.carga}"/>
            </h:commandLink>
            <br />
            <br />
            <h:commandLink action="#{notaController.prepareList}" value="#{bundle.CreateNotaShowAllLink}" immediate="true"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <h:link outcome="/inicio" value="#{bundle.CreateNotaIndexLink}"/>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Your question is missing anything that could be used to help troubleshoot your issue. Where is the view? What's `JSFUtil` and is it working properly?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar I have added the methods for messaging. I don't know any other code example to give because all controllers have the same create() method and for some of them it works but for this and others it does not.

Comment: @kolossus I have added the code for the create view. As I said before, JsfUtil method work for some methods, but not for others. In any method where I call the JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(message) sometimes the message is displayed and sometimes it doesn't

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar yes, no errors or warnings

Comment: Thanks for your colaboration, I checked my code and found that the problem was only when the return strings had ?faces-redirect=true. I removed that and it worked just fine. But the problem is that I need the redirected link as a requirement. How can I deal with that without having this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The faces message wasn't rendering it was being lost. I tried this code and it worked.

```
FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, msg, msg);
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
context.addMessage("successInfo", facesMsg);
```

I hope it works.

Comment: I did tried that before posting this. I was getting a warning console message about the messages, don't remember, but found out that the problem is when you put in the return strings ?faces-redirect=true

Comment: @Carlos Andres Read the accepted answer in this link [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685633/how-to-show-faces-message-in-the-redirected-page BalusC talks about a bug in messages when the page is redirected. Maybe it's your case.