# JSF, getting parameters from Flash scope do not work in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, jsf-2.2, flash-scope

our project is on

JSF 2.2 (Mojorra 2.2.0)

Servlet 3.0 : Jboss EAP 6.1

Facelets (XHTML)

When we put a parameter to Flash , we can not get it from another page in I.E. browser. We tried in I.E. 11 on different machines.
Strangely it is ok in Chrome, Opera.

Our code when putting parameter to Flash:

```
public String pageDirect(String url, ExtendedModel entity) {
    Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();
    flash.put("instance", entity);

    return url + "?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

And the code while getting param. from Flash:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ExtendedModel getInstance() {
    Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();
    instance = (ExtendedModel) flash.get("instance");
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = createInstance();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

While getting "instance" param from Flash, instance is null.
In debug mode, we can see: Flash.flashInnerMap  is {1={instance=2 - ORNEK SPOR SALONU}}

Returning param from Flash is null in IE (most of versions), but is ok in other browsers.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Whats the error? and wheres your code?

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? Tried the latest? See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: And did you try IE6 to?

Comment: You should specify concrete versions of JSF and IE and also provide some sample code.

Comment: we did not try IE6 , cause most of the users use the latest version IE 11

Comment: Mojarra 2.2.0 is definitely not "latest". It's over 2 years old already. Try the latest first then we can continue. There were quite some flash related bugs fixed after 2.2.0. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685633/how-to-show-faces-message-in-the-redirected-page/13685722#13685722