# flash.keep & flash.setKeepMessages(true) on redirection

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2, message, flash-scope

I am going through an example in *Anghel Leonard* book *Mastering Java Server Faces 2.2*.

The author demonstrates with an example on how preserve data for the next request on redirection when the bean is made is `@RequestScoped`.

[image]
[image]

This is the code for index.xhtml-

```
<h:body>
    <f:metadata> 
        <f:event type="preRenderView" 
            listener="#{playersBean.pullValuesFromFlashAction}"/> 
    </f:metadata>
    <h:messages />  
    <h:form>                       
        Name: <h:inputText value="#{playersBean.playerName}"/>
        Surname: <h:inputText value="#{playersBean.playerSurname}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="Register" 
            action="#{playersBean.addValuesToFlashAction()}"/>          
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

terms.xhtml-

```
<h:body>
    <h:messages />  
    Hello, <h:outputText value="#{flash.keep.playerName} #{flash.keep.playerSurname}"/>    
    <br/><br/>Terms &amp; Conditions ... ... ... ... ...
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="Reject" 
            action="#{playersBean.termsRejectedAction()}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Accept" 
            action="#{playersBean.termsAcceptedAction()}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

done.xhtml-

```
<h:head>
    <title></title>
</h:head>   
<h:body>
    <f:metadata> 
        <f:event type="preRenderView" 
            listener="#{playersBean.pullValuesFromFlashAction}"/> 
    </f:metadata>
    <h:messages />  
    <h:outputText value="#{playersBean.playerName} #{playersBean.playerSurname}"/> 
        successfully registered!           
</h:body>
```

And the backing bean-

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class PlayersBean {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PlayersBean.class.getName());
    private String playerName;
    private String playerSurname;
    public PlayersBean() {
    }
    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }
    public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }
    public String getPlayerSurname() {
        return playerSurname;
    }
    public void setPlayerSurname(String playerSurname) {
        this.playerSurname = playerSurname;
    }
    public String addValuesToFlashAction() {

        Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();
        flash.put("playerName", playerName);
        flash.put("playerSurname", playerSurname);
        return "terms?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    public void pullValuesFromFlashAction(ComponentSystemEvent e) {
        Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();
        playerName = (String) flash.get("playerName");
        playerSurname = (String) flash.get("playerSurname");
    }
    public String termsAcceptedAction() {
        Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();

        flash.setKeepMessages(true);
        pullValuesFromFlashAction(null);

        //do something with firstName, lastName 
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "First name: {0}", playerName);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Last name: {0}", playerSurname);

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Terms accepted and player registered!"));
        return "done?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    public String termsRejectedAction() {
        Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();

        flash.setKeepMessages(true);
        pullValuesFromFlashAction(null);

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Terms rejected! Player not registered!"));
        return "index?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

I think there was no need for these 2 lines-

```
flash.setKeepMessages(true);
pullValuesFromFlashAction(null);
```

as flash.keep on terms.xhtml page serves the same purpose.
The author seems to be confused here.

Or am I completely wrong & they do definitely serves a purpose over here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code chosen by the author is a bit confusing, from my point of view, however, it does what it is intended to do.

> flash.setKeepMessages(true);

This line tells JSF you want to keep the [`FacesMessage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.html) in the flash scope. That's a requirement when making a redirection, because more than one subsequent requests are involved and the messages would die from one request to another otherwise. The line is **necessary**.

> pullValuesFromFlashAction(null);

The line does nothing special, just grabs the name and the surname from the flash scope. It's just right to call it from `preRenderView` to load bean data from the flash scope, but it's **redundant** to invoke it from the action methods (unless you want to do some logging to see parameters are properly set). Anyway, if you're starting with JSF I encourage you to use JSF 2.2 which has a parameterless replacement for the `preRenderView` methods, called [`viewAction`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsf22-1377252.html).

Last but not least, I would recommend you going through [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21277621/1199132) I made some time ago showing an example for dealing with the flash scope, you might find it interesting.

**See also:**

- [JSF Keep Messages docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/Flash.html#isKeepMessages--)
- [How to show faces message in the redirected page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685633/how-to-show-faces-message-in-the-redirected-page)