# Retaining GET request query string parameters on JSF form submit

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, navigation, http-request-parameters

I have 3 pages:

- `main.xhtml`
- `agreement.xhtml`
- `generated.xhtml`

The `agreement.xhtml` needs two parameters to load correctly: `serviceId` and `site`. So, a normal url looks like this: `/app/agreement.xhtml?site=US&serviceId=AABBCC`.

I have this button on `agreement.xhtml`

```
<h:form>
   <h:commandButton value="Generate License File" action="#{agreement.generateMethod}" />   
</h:form>
```

The `@RequestScoped` bean `#{agreement}` has this method:

```
public String generateMethod(){
    .......
    return "generated";
}
```

I need that, on click, the `generateMethod()` method is executed, and after it's done, the user is redirected to the `generated.xhtml` page. What's happening is that, on click, the page browser sends the user to `/app/agreement.xhtml` and, since it's not sending the parameters `site` and `serviceId`, it crashes.

I tried making the `generateMethod()` return a `"generated?faces-redirect=true"`, but still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Use Faces Redirect = true.

See this [question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242240/jsf2-0-semantics-of-faces-redirect-true-in-commandlink-action-and-wh

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your concrete problem is caused because a JSF `<h:form>` submits by default to the current request URL without any query string. Look closer at the generated HTML output, you'll see

```html
<form action="/app/agreement.xhtml" ...>
```

You'd thus explicitly need to include those request parameters yourself. There are several ways to solve this. If you weren't sending a redirect, then you could just add them as hidden inputs to the JSF form.

```
<h:form>
    <input type="hidden" name="site" value="#{param.site}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="serviceId" value="#{param.serviceId}" />
    ...
</h:form>
```

Only, those parameters won't reappear in URL in browser's address bar. This isn't a problem if you're only using using ajax on the same page. The `<h:inputHidden>` is by the way not suitable as it will confusingly lose its value when a conversion or validation error occurs on the form.

In order to get them to reappear in URL, you need `<f:viewParam>` and `includeViewParams`. In order to get `includeViewParams` to work, you need to declare the following in **both** the source page `agreement.xhtml` ...

```html
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="site" value="#{agreement.site}" />
    <f:viewParam name="serviceId" value="#{agreement.serviceId}" />
</f:metadata>
```

... **and** the target page `generated.xhtml`:

```html
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="site" value="#{generated.site}" />
    <f:viewParam name="serviceId" value="#{generated.serviceId}" />
</f:metadata>
```

Now you can send a redirect including the view parameters as follows:

```
public String generateMethod() {
    // ...

    return "generated?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true";
}
```

Do note that the bean should be `@ViewScoped` in order to keep those parameters alive between opening the page with the form and submitting the form, also on validation errors. Otherwise, when sticking to a `@RequestScoped` bean, you should be retaining them as `<f:param>` in the command components:

```
<h:commandButton ...>
    <f:param name="site" value="#{generated.site}" />
    <f:param name="serviceId" value="#{generated.serviceId}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

There's no way to set them for `<f:ajax>` inside input components, your bean should then really be `@ViewScoped`.

---

Alternatively, if you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) already, then you could also just replace the `<h:form>` by `<o:form>` as follows (see also [showcase example](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/form)):

```html
<o:form>
```

That's basically all. This will generate a `<form action>` with current query string included.

```html
<form action="/app/agreement.xhtml?site=US&serviceId=AABBCC" ...>
```

Those request parameters are then just available in the request parameter map of the form submit. You don't need additional metadata/viewparams and you also don't need to send a redirect and your bean can be kept `@RequestScoped`, if necessary.

```
public String generateMethod() {
    // ...

    return "generated";
}
```

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-fviewparam-and-fviewaction-be-used-for)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o)

Comment: Will the `h:input`s, `h:message` and other elements inside the original `h:form` still work after switching it to `o:form`? Or is there any additional work needed to be done? The original commandButton's (type `submit`, using POST) can still return `void/null` too?

Answer (score 6):

Your `generateMethod` would have to return

```
return "generated?site=US&amp;serviceId=AABBCC&amp;faces-redirect=true";
```

You can even replace `&amp;` with `&` but escape it in your xhtml.

In your `generated.xhtml` you can catch the parameters that are being passed with `<f:viewParam>` like this

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="site" value="#{yourBean.site}"/><!--Make sure you have a setter-->
    <f:viewParam name="serviceId" value="#{yourBean.serviceId}"/><!--Make sure you have a setter-
</f:metadata>
<h:head>
```