# How to ignore filter for postback calls

Tags: ajax, jsf, postback, servlet-filters

I have a filter which requires an id-parameter (GET). This works fine when I add the parameter in the navigation links. But when I stay at the same site (e.g. ajax calls), the filter shouts and screams, because the id-parameter is lost.

Is there a chance to ignore the filter if the request come from ajax? 
something like

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {...}
    ...
}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution which works fine

```
private boolean isAJAXRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    boolean check = false;
    String facesRequest = request.getHeader("Faces-Request");
    if (facesRequest != null && facesRequest.equals("partial/ajax")) {
        check = true;
    }
    return check; 
}
```

in the beginning of the filter, just add it like:

```
@Override 
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    if(isAJAXRequest(req)){
        System.out.println("IGNORE THIS FILTER, AJAX");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the functional requirement more clearly. You are currently too vague and mixing several concepts.

What exactly do you want to check on?

1. It is a GET request.
2. It is not a JSF ajax POST request.
3. It is not a POST request.

Your current question title *"How to ignore filter for postback calls"* covers 2 and 3. Your current question body *"which requires an id-parameter (GET)"* covers 1. Your own answer covers 2.

This is really not clear. So, I'll just show how to cover each of them:

1. To check if it's a GET request:

   ```
   if ("GET".equals(request.getMethod())) {
       // It's a GET request.
   }
   ```
2. To check if it's not a JSF ajax POST request:

   ```
   if (!"partial/ajax".equals(request.getHeader("Faces-Request"))) {
       // It's not a JSF ajax request.
   }
   ```
3. To check if it's not a POST request:

   ```
   if (!"POST".equals(request.getMethod())) {
       // It's not a POST request.
   }
   ```

They all are quite different:

1. This not only excludes POST, but also e.g. PUT and OPTIONS requests.
2. This doesn't exclude synchronous JSF POST requests (e.g. submit button without `<f:ajax>`).
3. This also excludes all other kinds of POST requests.

Think twice and ultimately just use the right tool for the job.

---

An alternative would be to retain the current GET query string in the form action URL (i.e. solving the problem by its roots instead of workarounding it). This is answered here: [Retaining GET request query string parameters on JSF form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734230/retaining-get-request-query-string-parameters-on-jsf-form-submit/).

Answer (score 0):

[This workaround](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2009/06/27/is-it-an-ajax-request-or-a-normal-request/) just works:

```
private boolean isAjax(HttpServletRequest request) {
    //Return if current request header is equals to "XMLHttpRequest"
    return "XMLHttpRequest".equals((request).getHeader("X-Requested-With"));
}
```

Comment: sadly, this solution doesn't? see my own anser at the bottom