# Redirect to the same page in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm using the following action method to make a redirect to the same page.

```
public String localeAction()
{
    String viewId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId();
    return viewId + "?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

This method is called, when a value from a `<p:selectOneMenu>` holding a list of different languages is selected on the master template.

---

If the current page URL has some query-string parameters appended to it like so,

`http://localhost:8080/Project/public_resources/ProductDetails.jsf?id=5`

The parameter `id` is lost after this redirection has been made.

Is there a way to redirect to the current page along with all query-string parameters intact - they should not be lost?

Comment: Try appending the returning outcome with: "includeViewParam" like this : `?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true` as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17745573/2459449

Comment: The problem arises with request scoped managed beans where appending `includeViewParams` to `ViewId` doesn't work. The action method is invoked, on the `onchange` event of `<p:selectOneMenu>` (which is an AJAX request) which is located at the master template. It seems I have to decorate all managed beans with `@ViewScoped` throughout the application.

Comment: I think you'd decorate just those associated with views that use the Ajax's fonctionnality.

Comment: The `onchange` event of  `<p:selectOneMenu>` is an AJAX request as always which is located at the master page template. Hence, it is available to all pages associated with that template. Therefore, it needs view scoped beans everywhere.

Comment: Does it work for view scoped managed-beans ?

Comment: Yes it works for view scoped beans.