# Why tree ajax events in primefaces don't work when bean scope is request?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My xhtml code is:

```
<p:tree id="attachTree" style="width: 100%;" value="#{detailsTaskBacking.attachRootNode}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{detailsTaskBacking.selectedNode}" var="node">
<p:ajax event="select" async="false" update=":roteiroAttachTab:formAttachForm:mediaPdf" listener="#{detailsTaskBacking.onNodeSelect}"/>
<p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
<h:outputText value="#{text['tasksbacking.tabAttach']}"/>
 </p:treeNode>
<p:treeNode type="file" expandedIcon="ui-icon-document" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-document">
 <h:outputText value="#{node.name}"/>
</p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

And my bean code is:

```
@request
...
public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {...}
```

When run the project in debug mode selectedNode for argument event is null, why?

Why in primefaces tree ajax events not work when bean scope is request? I tested this with one bean in view scope and the selectedNode is not null, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will happen if the model behind `#{detailsTaskBacking.attachRootNode}` incompatibly changes during postback. E.g. when it's reinitialized to `null`. You need to make sure that the model is exactly the same across postbacks on the same view. In case of a request scoped bean, you'd need to make sure that you prepare exactly the same model in `@PostConstruct` as it was when the form is being displayed. Another way is to just make the bean `@ViewScoped` so that the same bean instance lives as long as you postback on the same view.

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)
- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked) - point 4

Comment: Does that mean that, if a request parameter is accessed in the backing bean, it should always be accessed in `@PostConstruct` (when in request-scope)?

Comment: That's correct. You can use `@ManagedProperty` to set a request parameter as a bean property before `@PostConstruct` runs. However, if parameters depend on postback actions taken place beforehand on the same view, you'd better just put the bean in the view scope. There it is for.

Comment: Initially this id is populated but when I click on the node it is null. In scope view work but i need use request scope. 
the problem is that initially the id is in the url but when click on node not. I saw it doing print context.getRequestURL(). why?

Comment: Because you didn't pass it when submitting the form. That's answered in among others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734230/retaining-get-request-query-string-parameters-on-jsf-form-submit/

Comment: thanks BalusC! use this code <o:form includeRequestParams="true"> in form .