# Ajax calls are not working when bean is changes to @Scope("request") with PrimeFaces

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

I am new to Spring/JSF.

I have a controller which is annotated by `@Component` which have a `@Autowired` class `UserClass` which has,

```
@Scope(value=org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
```

I need to create a new `UserClass` instance for each new request so my controller is annotated with `@Scope("request")`  which works perfectly(Creating new instance for each request) with this annotation.

But it broke the ajax calls in `<p:dataTable>` selection, commondLink, `<f:setPropertyActionListener...`

NOTE : if I change the `@Scope("request")` to `@ViewScoped` the ajax works but my `UserClass` becomes singleton and all the data is shared between the threads.

I googled and got to know we need to either use JSF annotations or Spring but here I am using only Spring annotations.

And I found this, [PrimeFaces doesn't work when bean scope is request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422401/why-tree-ajax-events-in-primefaces-dont-work-when-bean-scope-is-request) but couldn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

A component library like Primefaces heavily relies in a stateful model, which means using at least the view scope in your managed beans. If you use the request scope you'll be recreating the managed bean for every single request, **including ajax requests**, which I guess it isn't what you want (not the way to go with JSF, at least).

Your best is to use a custom Spring Scope in order to emulate the JSF view scope. I like [this approach](https://www.primefaces.org/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/) from the PF team (a bit old post, but still you can tune it for newer Spring versions) or [this one](https://github.com/stephanrauh/JSF-on-Spring-Boot/blob/master/UnderstandingScopes/src/main/java/com/liferay/faces/demos/spring/ViewScope.java), which is more elaborated.