# JSF Access control on direct object

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF page contentEdit.xhtml which accepts a request parameter "code" to load the content for editing and other operations related. To provide access control, I create a filter ContentAccessFilter and applies it to contentEdit.xhtml to check whether the current user is authorized to the content which is identified by "code".

Fragment of ContentAccessFilter:

```
        boolean isAuthorized = false;
        String userId = httpReq.getRemoteUser();
        String code = httpReq.getParameter("code");

        if (code != null && !code.isEmpty())
        {
            ContentDAO dao = ContentDAO.getInstance();
            isAuthorized = dao.isContentAuthorized(code, userId);
        }

        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            httpRes.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            return;
        }
```

For the first entry of the contentEdit.xhtml, the filter works properly as the code parameter always exists during the first entry by calling such as /contentArea.xhtml?code=cnn from an anchor html tag. However, the code parameter is lost when there is subsequent operations on contentEdit.xhtml. For example, I have buttons like these.

```
<p:commandButton value="Download" action="#{contentView.downloadContent}"/>
<p:commandButton value="Publish" action="#{contentView.publishContent}"/>
```

Clicking the button will call the same URL as contentEdit.xhtml, while the parameter code is not included in the request URL. This missing parameter fails in the filter.

Is using a Servlet Filter a proper way to achieve the access control in this case? If it is, how to include a request parameter when triggers a commandButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters are a great way to implement authorization in a web app... you're on the right track.

The best way would be to use your filter but store the `code` parameter value in a session (`javax.servlet.http.HttpSession`), that way the parameter doesn't need to be passed in the query string with each request. You would set the `code` attribute in the session data on the first request and retrieve it whenever a new request is received.

If you must use the query string to pass the `code` value with each request, you'll need to use the `includeViewParams` parameter in the query string creation to preserve the `code` parameter in the generated URLs. BalusC (the JSF God) explains this better than anyone... https://stackoverflow.com/a/17745573/3858863

Comment: Thanks for help. I think the session way should be the best for my need. My form is a multi-part form, which introduce some complexity when using f:param, as I am using a servlet 2.5 container.