# PrimeFaces Datatable filtering removed when sorting with o:form includeRequestParams="true"

Tags: primefaces, filter, datatable, omnifaces, http-request-parameters

this is an issue following this one: [PrimeFaces datatable.filter() and url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649367/primeface-datatable-filter-and-url-parameter/)

is use PrimeFaces-5.1 and omnifaces-2.1 to render a datatable with pagination, filtering and sorting while using request parameters.
my datatable is constructed like this:

```
<o:form includeRequestParams="true">
    <p:dataTable id="hostStateHistoryTable" value="#{HostHistoryBean.hostStateHistoryList}" var="status" widgetVar="statusTable"
    filteredValue="#{HostHistoryBean.filteredHostStateHistoryList}" 
    rowStyleClass="#{status.state eq 0 ? 'up' : null} #{status.state   eq 1 ? 'down' : null} #{status.state eq 2 ? 'unreachable' : null}"
    rows="50" paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{PageLinks} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,50,100">
        <p:column sortBy="#{status.stateTime}">
            <f:facet name="header">Start Time</f:facet>
            <h:outputText id="Start" value="#{status.stateTime}"     />
        </p:column> 
        ... all columns
    </p:dataTable>
</o:form>
```

But Sorting is removing the PrimeFaces Datatable Filtering. 
I can sort alone and filter alone without problem, but when i sort the datable after filtering it remove the filter. again Clicking on the same filter won't do anything but filtering on another value will display the expected result. 
It seems that the o:form will resend the request, including attribute, instead of using the datatable filteredValue.

Edit:
I uploaded an eclipse based MCVE project here: http://www.dacave.fr/stackoverflow/test.faces.rar

Comment: does changing it to h:form make it work again? And please create an mcve so others can (try to) reproduce more easily

Comment: changing it to h:form make every functionality useless due to request parameters not beeing used by ajax call

Comment: Ok let me reformulate: does plain sorting AND filtering without using you parameter work in the PrimeFaces version you use? Otherwise we might be chasing hosts

Comment: It work as expected (when not polled) on other pages yes

Comment: A MCVE would help. I guess the mistake is in loading logic.

Comment: Ok i prepared one, what would be the best way to share it? the code directly in post? host the project somewhere?

Comment: so i just added a MCVE to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i found out that filteredValue was reseted on each ajax call because of the @RequestScoped.
I think i was kind of mixing up things.
So i switched all @ManagedBeans to @Named
then i created a new @SessionScoped Bean with most of the attributes and i @inject a @RequestScoped bean with the request based attributes into it.

Now everything works as expected

Comment: View scoped data can better be stored in a view scoped bean, not in a session scoped bean. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/

Comment: thanks really interesting :)
I switched to ViewScope and the two sets of data are in a more coherent state

Comment: So this means that the backing bean behind `filteredValue` have to be in another backing bean that is `@ViewScoped`? I also have that property in a `@RequestScoped` (and yes, I now fully understand that it got reset on each AJAX call).