# Showing wrong bookmark url when using Internet Explorer "Add to Favorites" Context Menu

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces

I have a webpage with 2 panels left panel and a right panel. Inside each panel i have a form like below with various input fields and a command button to submit the form:

```
<h:form id="oneForm">
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" styleClass="submitClass" 
        action="#{oneBean.submitInfo()}" onclick="closeDialog();" update=":createInfo">
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

When i open the webpage in the internet Explorer the Address bar has following URL:
http://www.example.com/information.jsf#deal=001#alter=1

but when i right click on the above form and use "Add to Favorites" context menu and save the Favorite and then check the URL saved, it shows following
http://www.example.com/information.jsf

All the hash information is gone? when i right click the same form and click on the "Properties" on IE Context Menu the URL shown in the properties tab is the correct one "http://www.example.com/information.jsf#deal=001#alter=1" and it should take this but it does not, dont know why, strange behavior.

A very similar question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17745573/1297935 but that has to do with URL params and i am working with URL hash fragments, also i am not submitting any form here i am just right clicking the form and Adding it to favorite.

I need to get the proper url with hash values to the Favorites added by user. Any help on this will be appreciated? thanks!

Comment: did you mean `?deal=001&alter=1` at the end of the url?

Comment: no, i am using url hash fragments and not url parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i tried many different things and it came out to be that it is a issue with internet explorer as follows and NOT with the JSF Forms:

if i use IE context Menu using right click to add favorite all url hash tags are omitted(all url parameters are retained fine) and if i use Cntl+D or the top right corner star icon to add favorite all url hash tags are retained and everything is fine. may be there is a quick fix for this hence i will post a new question for internet explorer.

i have added a question:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/34648398/1297935